# How to add one array into another equalling another array

Tags: java, arrays

How would one go about adding the contents of one array into another array, to be equal to another array.

```
double[] array1 = new double[4];
double[] array2 = new double[4];
double[] array3 = new double[4];

double input;
double number1;
double number2;

System.out.println("Welcome. Please enter the first number in 1st set: ");

// add 4 numbers into 1st array

System.out.println("Please enter the first number in the 2nd set: ");

// add 4 numbers into 2nd array

for (int i = 0; i < array3.length; i++){
    array3[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];

    System.out.println(" #" + (i+1) + " in the array is " + array3[i]);
}
```

I do not know why the code at the bottom does not work. No error messages come up, just 0's in the code.

Should I do this:

```
int number1 = array1[1];
int number2 = array[1];

int finalNumber = number1 + number2;

finalNumber = array3[1];
```

That just seems unnecessarily complicated.

*Edit*

This is the code I use to assign the variables in the array.

```
System.out.println("Welcome. Please enter the first number in 1st set: ");

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    System.out.println(i+1 + ": ");
    input = TextIO.getlnDouble();   // Retrieves input
    input = array1[i];
}

System.out.println("Please enter the first number in the 2nd set: ");

for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
    System.out.println("Number: ");
    input = TextIO.getlnDouble();   // Retrieves input
    input = array2[i];
}
```

Comment: How are you setting values in array1 and array2? I don't see it

Comment: Might be the case that you are not setting the value correctly in array1 and array2, My friend debug it to make sure what are you doing

Comment: @Jordan.McBride Please provide your code for adding values in `array1` and `array2`, the code you have posted looks fine. So the issue might be while assigning the values.

Comment: @Jordan.McBride Please see my answer. You are assigning the values wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning values wrong way.

You should use `array1[i]=input;` instead of `input = array1[i];`.See below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    System.out.println(i+1 + ": ");
    input = TextIO.getlnDouble();   // Retrieves input
    array1[i] = input;
}

System.out.println("Please enter the first number in the 2nd set: ");

for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
    System.out.println("Number: ");
    input = TextIO.getlnDouble();   // Retrieves input
    array2[i] = input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is neat and looks fine.

Did you print and check the values of first two arrays?

Since you already had the line

double[] array3 = new double[4];

there won't be a problem with your for loop. Just print the first two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args){
        double[] array1 = new double[4];
        double[] array2 = new double[4];
        double[] array3 = new double[4];

        double input;
        double number1;
        double number2;

        System.out.println("Welcome. Please enter the first number in 1st set: ");

        array1[0] = 1;
        array1[1] = 2;
        array1[2] = 3;
        array1[3] = 4;

        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
                 System.out.println("Number: ");
                 input = TextIO.getlnDouble();   // Retrieves input
                 //input = array2[i]; <--- change this to
                 array2[i] = input;
             }


        for (int i = 0; i < array3.length; i++){
            array3[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];

            System.out.println(" #" + (i+1) + " in the array is " + array3[i]);
        }
    }
```

and my output is

```
Welcome. Please enter the first number in 1st set: 
Please enter the first number in the 2nd set: 
 #1 in the array is 2.0
 #2 in the array is 4.0
 #3 in the array is 6.0
 #4 in the array is 8.0
```

maybe it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your code

```
for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
                 System.out.println("Number: ");
                 input = TextIO.getlnDouble();   // Retrieves input
                 input = array2[i]; <--- change this to
             }
```

thats the right one

```
for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
                     System.out.println("Number: ");
                     input = TextIO.getlnDouble();   // Retrieves input
                     array2[i] = input;
                 }
```

and for the first array too

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly assigning values to the arrays.

The variable that you want to assign a value *to*, goes on the left hand side of the `=` operator.  The variable that you are assigning a value *from* goes on the right hand side.

Currently you are assigning the value in `array1[i]` to `input`.
Since you want to assign the value in `input` to a position in the array, you need to change

```
input = array1[i];
```

to

```
array1[i] = input;
```

And likewise with the second array.